# When and why to use $A.reportError?

Tags: javascript, reporting, error, aura, documentation

In the documentation [Using JavaScript Promises](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm) it is mentioned

> To show an error message in a catch() method, use $A.reportError()

Why would I want to use `$A.reportError` that at all? I could use `console.error()`, for instance, to report all errors caught in `catch`.

Also in that docs I read the following statement

> If you don't have a catch() method, keep an eye on your browser’s
>   console during development for reports about uncaught errors in a
>   promise.

This phrase **during development for reports about uncaught errors** made me wonder, does it mean that we need `catch()` and `$A.reportError` for a developer to be able to conveniently spot any unhanded errors during development? And theoretically, in production we shouldn't even get these unhanded errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `$A.reportError` does a little more than just report the error on the console. It gets the action of the exception, if available, and uses that as description. It will also wrap a non-Aura error, so that required information can be set to the error message.

It seems that it will also post the error to the server:

> Post the action failure to the server, where we can keep track of it for bad client code. But don't keep re-posting if the report of failure fails.

This is from the [Logger.js file on the archived Aura repository on GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/0fb5aa1d14f648ad436814349f23ce02b0cfab75/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/Logger.js#L136).

---

As for "why would I use that instead of `console.error`?" my best bets would be that:

1. since it posts something to the server, it will probably get logged somewhere, like on an `EventLogFile` object;
2. it will be handled by the framework, instead of just showing the error message on the console (it will probably pop that modal showing a "component error" message).

The second one is more likely, because the documentation says:

> Throwing an error in a promise doesn’t trigger window.onerror, which is where the framework configures its global error handler.

And if this is the case, then it will show the popup to the current user, which is likely undesirable, but it will provide something that the user can show/copy to the org administrator.